# Laravel homesetad/vagrant curl not working

Tags: php, laravel, curl

For some reason, I can't use CURL to send post requests in homestead/vagrant. It just returns null and here is my code.

Additional, headers are not being set, even if it's application/json it returns HTML/charset.

any clues?

```
$ch = curl_init(env('app_url') . 'applications/' . $position->ats_reference . '/import');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: application/json"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode([
       'token' => $user->token,
       'data' => [$data]
    ]));
curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
dd($info);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: when you SSH to homestead can you use curl in command line ?

Comment: @teeyo if i curl -X GET http://example.com it returns the page so the answer is yes.

Comment: what does `curl_error()` tell you?

Comment: @delboy1978uk It tells me "". So nothing

Comment: after you did the exec?

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg what that tells me is that it's not a homestead issue, did you try your code on a public json api ? like a weather api or google maps api just to see if the issue is curl ?

Comment: Get requests work. If it's to any help, it works when I send the request from a Job in laravel. Picked up by a worker.

Comment: @delboy1978uk yes after curl_exec($ch); I run dd(curl_error($ch));